# subprocess and extra args

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
args = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/java/jre/lib/i386/:/opt/java/jre/lib/amd64/ exec /opt/java/jre/bin/java -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'.split()
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, the result I recieve is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "launch.py", line 29, in <module>
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__ errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Without the LD_LIBRARY_PATH part, it works fine. However, I need it.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You should import shlex then use shlex.split to make sure the command is split the same way as with the shell, respecting quotes etc. Also if you use shell=True you may have to not split. If already in a list, you can use shlex.join(command_parts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a method that avoids using the shell:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from os import environ

env = dict(os.environ)
env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/opt/java/jre/lib/i386/:/opt/java/jre/lib/amd64/'
args = ['/opt/java/jre/bin/java', '-Xincgc', '-Xmx1G', '-jar', 'craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar']
p = Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=env)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `shell = True` to the `Popen` call:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The syntax you're using to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a shell syntax, so it's necessary to execute the command through the shell.

Comment: I actually did try that, but I get nothing out of the following: p.stderr.readline()

Comment: @dbdii407: I think that's a separate problem. Why not post it a separate question?

Comment: Why create another question when the original has yet to be resolved? ;)